# How to customize the size of each subplot in matplotlib so that all subplots have equal x-axis scales?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

def plot2(fold,start,w_ratios,t_width=1):
    data = np.load('%s_hp1.npy' %fold)
    inner_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 8, subplot_spec=gs[start], wspace=(1 - t_width)+0.1, hspace=0.3, width_ratios=w_ratios)#, height_ratios=[1,1,0.4])
    for i in range(len(data)):
        ax = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid[i])
        ax.plot(data[i][0] *10,'r') ; ax.plot(data[i][1] *10,'b') ; ax.plot(data[i][2] *10,'g') ; ax.set_xlim([-1,len(data[i][0])+1]) ; ax.grid(True); ax.set_ylim([10,22])
        ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,len(data[i][0]),1000)) ; ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(0,len(data[i][0]),1000)*200/1000,fontsize=10)
        ax.set_title('%s-run%d' %(fold,i+1),fontsize=16)
        fig.add_subplot(ax)    

def get_with_rations(fold):
    ww = []
    data = np.load('%s_hp1.npy' %fold)
    for i in range(8):
        try: ww.append(len(data[i][0]))
        except: ww.append(0)
    return ww

folds = ['wt','wt_d394','mut','mut_d394']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,15),facecolor='w')
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(8,1)
gs.update(left=0.03, right=0.98, bottom=0.03, top=0.98, wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)
start = 0
for fold in folds:
    ws = get_with_rations(fold)
    plot2(fold,start,ws)
    start += 1

plt.show()
```

Which gives this plot:

[image]

As you can see all the "row" subplots have the **same** scale for `x-axis`, but `x-axis` scale is not the same if we compare subplots of "row1" with e.g. "row3". 
In other words, the subplot in "row3" has extremely large x-axis scale compared to other subplots which doesn't look right.
Is the a way to make all subplots to have exactly same x-axis scale?

Comment: IF you strictly want the subplots to have same width (size) of all subplots, you can use either 4x5 subplot grid or 5x4 grid. But then, one of the subgrids will be empty because you have 19 subplots and not 20.  Otherwise, you can't have same scale with different plots in each row.